# Need to modify the SelectCommand parameter for SqlDataSource from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a SqlDataSource that I am trying to modify in C# ASP.NET from my code behind page.  The code in the page is:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TEST_SERVER %>" 
      ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TEST_SERVER.ProviderName %>" 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to dynamically modify the SelectCommand parameter for SqlDataSource1 but in the codebehind page it does not seem to be available.

Am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: Does it show data? If yes then the DataSet and Adapter are configured elsewhere. Be glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select command will be there as soon as you add your ending '>' to your open tag.

Try this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TEST_SERVER %>" 
      ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TEST_SERVER.ProviderName %>">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Darn typos ;)

Comment: Yup. That was the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is available, just do:

```
 SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand="Select a , b, c from table_c";
```

The SelectCommand property is as string. Read the [documentation here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectcommand.aspx)

If you want to modify the select CommandType, use the SelectCommandType as so (stored proc):

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommandType=SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
```