# C# ASP.NET DetailsView - display first record only on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, detailsview

I am currently hiding all rows from the database in the GridView until the CommandField (Select) field in the DetailsView is pressed. 
How can I display the first record on page load in C#?

Any help is much appreciated :)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView12" DataKeyNames="DealId" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ShowHeader="False" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DealId" ItemStyle-CssClass="gv-class" SortExpression="DealId" Visible="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DealName" ItemStyle-CssClass="gv-class" SortExpression="DealName" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DealDescription" ItemStyle-CssClass="gv-class" SortExpression="DealDescription" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DealLocation" ItemStyle-CssClass="gv-class" SortExpression="DealLocation" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DealPrice" ItemStyle-CssClass="gv-class" SortExpression="DealPrice" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ImagePath" ItemStyle-CssClass="gv-class" SortExpression="ImagePath" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" CssClass="image-class" runat="server" Height="50px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImagePath" ItemStyle-CssClass="dv-img" SortExpression="ImagePath"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DealId" ItemStyle-CssClass="dv-1 float" SortExpression="DealId" Visible="false"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DealName" ItemStyle-CssClass="dv-2 float" SortExpression="DealName" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataFie`enter code here`ld="DealDescription" ItemStyle-CssClass="dv-3 float" SortExpression="DealDescription" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DealLocation" ItemStyle-CssClass="dv-4 float" SortExpression="DealLocation" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DealPrice" ItemStyle-CssClass="dv-5 float" SortExpression="DealPrice" />                                
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several ways of doing this. May I suggest having two different SqlDataSource.SelectCommands for your gridview?

First, delete `SELECTCOMMAND="Select * from table"` from your SQLDATASOURCE in the markup, then create the selectcommands in your CodeBehind with two methods.

One that loads in Page_Load when postback is false, and another that loads when select is clicked, and postback happens.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
{
sqlcommandall();
}
else
{
sqlcommandone();
}
}
protected void sqlcommandall()
{
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from table order by id";
}
protected void sqlcommandone()
{
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select top 1 * from table order by id";
}
```

the other ways, are the same, except your can trigger the selectcommands by adding `OnLoad="GridView12_Load"` to the GridView12 declaration in markup, and instead of the Page_load method, you'd use:

```
protected void GridView12_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
{
sqlcommandall();
}
else
{
sqlcommandone();
}
}
```

Here's some info on changing select command: [Need to modify the SelectCommand parameter for SqlDataSource from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708628/need-to-modify-the-selectcommand-parameter-for-sqldatasource-from-c-sharp?s=2|1.4248)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much @BasicIsaac , I can see how this would work :) I am still coming into some difficulty. My querys are:    select * from Deals order by DealId for my sqlcommandall()      AND    select top 1 DealId from Deals WHERE DealId='101'order by DealId for my sqlcommandone(). I am getting an error: A field or property with the name 'DealName' was not found on the selected data source.   I have checked and there definitely is a field in my Deals table called DealName.

Comment: It looks like your second SqlCommand is only retrieving one field, where it should retrieve all the fields. Try `select top 1 DealId, DealName, DealDescription, DealPrice, ImagePath from Deals WHERE DealId='101'order by DealId` include every single field that needs to be shown in the gridview in your select commands.